# Check whether this is indeed a counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$; let $Q := A \times B$; and let $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. The problem is to give a counterexample to the proposition that if the Riemann integral $\int_{Q}f$ exists then $\int_{x \in A}\int_{y \in B}f(x,y)$ and $\int_{y \in B}\int_{x \in A}f(x,y)$ exist.

I am not very sure if my counterexample is indeed a counterexample to the proposition.
Let $A := B := [0,1]$, so that $Q = A^{2}$, and let $f: (x,y) \mapsto 1$ if $y = 1/2$ and $\mapsto 0$ otherwise. Then, since $A \times \{1/2\}$, the set of discontinuities of $f$, has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, the integral $\int_{A^{2}}f$ exists. On the other hand, since for all $x \in A$, the set of discontinuities of the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\{1/2\}$, which has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$, so $\int_{y\in A}f(x,y)$ exists for all $x \in A$, and hence from Fubini's theorem it follows that $\int_{x \in A}\int_{y \in A}f(x,y)$ exists. But the set $[0,1] \times \{1/2\}$ does not have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$, so $\int_{x \in A}f(x,y)$ does not exist, and we are "done".

Comment: The set $[0,1]\times \{1/2\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your example is a counterexample.

For every $y$, the function $$x\mapsto (x,y)$$

is a continuous function, thus its integral over $[0,1]$ exists.

$$g(y) = \int_A f(x,y) dx = \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx = \begin{cases}\int_{0}^1 0dx & y\neq 1/2\\
\int_0^1 1dx & y=1/2\end{cases}=\begin{cases}0 & y\neq 1/2\\
1 & y=1/2\end{cases}$$

You can then calculate $\int_A g(y)dy = \int_A \int_A f(x,y) dx dy$

---

I think a counterexample can be found if $A$ or $B$ is a discrete set and $f$ is completely dicontinuous (so, for example, $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\{0,1\}$ and $f(x,y) =0$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. What a blatant error I have committed...